# How can I pass a fake media stream to firefox from command line?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am developing a java/selenium based application and need to pass media i.e. audio and/or video files to the browser.

I have been able to successfully do this in Chrome using the below code snippet:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome(); 
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--allow-file-access-from-files",
            "--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream",
            "--allow-file-access",
            "--use-file-for-fake-audio-capture=D:\\PATH\\TO\\WAV\\xxx.wav",
            "--use-fake-device-for-media-stream");
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

Are there similar options available in Firefox 33.1 to achieve the same capability?

If not, how can this be done?

Answer (score 7):

## Fake Webcam (Chrome & Firefox)

Here's a way setup a fake webcam from the command-line on Linux.

### Dependencies

- Linux (I'm using Ubuntu)
- [FFMpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) (video streaming tool)
- [v4l2loopback](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback) (enables a fake video device)

### Installing v4l2loopback (Fake Webcam)

```sh
# 1. Install v4l2loopback kernel module from apt
sudo apt install v4l2loopback-dkms

# 2. Enable the "fake webcam", via v4l2loopback kernel module
sudo modprobe v4l2loopback devices=1 card_label="My Fake Webcam" exclusive_caps=1
```

### Video File (Looped) as Fake Webcam

```sh
# Link video file (on loop) to the "fake webcam"
ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -re -i ./MYFILE.mp4 -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -threads 0 -f v4l2 /dev/video0
```

### Desktop Video as Fake Webcam

```sh
# Link desktop video stream to the "fake webcam"
ffmpeg -f x11grab -r 15 -s 1280x720 -i :0.0+0,0 -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -threads 0 -f v4l2 /dev/video0
```

The great part about this is that it works for both Firefox and Chrome! As it fakes the webcam at the kernel level.

Test your fake webcam here: https://webcamtests.com/

**Chrome Test (Desktop Feed)**
[image]

**Firefox Test (Desktop Feed)**
[image]

### Disable Fake Webcam

If you need to disable it...

```
# To disable the fake webcam, simply remove it from the kernel
sudo modprobe --remove v4l2loopback
```

Anyway, hope someone finds this useful!

Comment: Could you elaborate on your answer? I tried this: `sudo modprobe v4l2loopback devices=1 card_label="My Fake Webcam" exclusive_caps=1 | ffmpeg -f x11grab -r 15 -s 1280x720 -i :0.0+0,0 -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -threads 0 -f v4l2 /dev/video0` but Chrome still doesn't recognize my camera. Usually I'm using this approach, which works for Firefox only: https://askubuntu.com/a/972831/54817, but I'm looking for a Chrome solution to be able to use my camera for gotomeeting.

Comment: Btw, I'm using Chromium Version 87.0.4280.66.

Comment: Got it to work now: The exclusive_caps=1 only got recognized by chrome after I restarted my pc!

Comment: You shouldn't have to restart the computer (at least I didn't) but you do need to ensure that all instances of Chrome are terminated first, use the System Monitor to check if any are running.

Comment: @BenWinding: it's not working on the server where we don't have a webcam. Can you please help

Answer (score 5):

Firefox has only these capabilities,
**browserName, 
browserVersion,
platformName, 
acceptInsecureCerts,
pageLoadStrategy,
proxy,
setWindowRect,
timeouts,
unhandledPromptBehavior**

But as a option, there is one as in a below code,

> options.addPreference("media.navigator.streams.fake", true);

Hope it will help you to solve this situation.