# How to use fake-web cam on mozilla firefox using selenium java

Tags: selenium, firefox, automation

I am trying to automate a website that has a webcam stream in it. In order to automate it, I need some way to fake a webcam.

I know the option `-use-fake-device-for-media-stream` simulates a webcam in Chrome. This is working for me in Chrome. Now I need to get the same working in Firefox.

I got the following information [from internet](https://blog.andyet.com/2014/09/29/testing-webrtc-applications/) while researching on this.
"In Firefox, a special `fake:true` variable in the `getUserMedia()` calls will achieve this".

I did not understand how to code this up. Can anyone advice please? I am using java based selenium.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31859459/1119381. Unfortunately unanswered.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done in Firefox at various levels:

- System
- User Level
- Profile Level etc

Set following props in either  *user.js*, *pref.js*  or  *channel-prefs.js*

```
pref("media.navigator.permission.disabled", true);
pref("media.navigator.streams.fake", true);
```

OR

```
user_pref("media.navigator.permission.disabled", true);
user_pref("media.navigator.streams.fake", true);
```

Then reboot your machine or restart firefox service.

After that call your URL which invokes `getUserMedia()`  Firefox will display Fake Audio/Video.

Comment: is it possible to set a specific stream?

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
profile.setPreference('media.navigator.streams.fake', true);
```

Comment: Do you know what version of FF was this added in?

Comment: It's also possible to set this in `about:config`